# Get erb view from inside layout

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

I am trying to get the name of the current view being loaded into `layout.erb`. I am trying to inject a js file and a css file into the layout head. I am building the name for those files based on the name of the erb view:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/devcss/<%= viewName%>.css">
<script src="/devjs/<%= viewName %>.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can I do this from the layout template?

**UPDATE**:I am not interested in knowing how to inject the script in a specific place in layout, which I think content_for is used for. What I need to knok in the example above is how to determine the **viewName** variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert the following into application.html.erb after inside `head` tag

```
<%= "#{yield(:scripts)}".html_safe if content_for?(:scripts) %>
```

and in the individual erb, insert similar to the following

```
<% content_for :scripts do %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/devcss/<%= viewName%>.css">
    <script src="/devjs/<%= viewName %>.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<% end %>
```

This will allow you to insert page specific codes into head and other tags not accessible to your individual erbs

Comment: I know i can pass paramaters to my erbs, i was just wondering if there is an easy way for the layout to know which erb is including

Comment: `content_for` is from Rails, not Sinatra. Sinatra doesn’t have `content_for` out of the box, you would need to use something like the [ContentFor extension](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/content_for.html) from [Sinatra::Contrib](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/) which uses `yield_content` rather than `yield`.

Comment: Also `if :scripts` will _always_ be true, since `:scripts` is a symbol. I guess you mean to test if the template added content for that symbol, I don’t know if there is a way to do that in Rails.

Comment: @matt is spot on, I have updated the code to use `content_for?`